# getting http 404 when testing Spring Boot with Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-test, spring-cloud-contract

***TLDR:*** spring boot test does not find url endpoint defined using spring security

**Long story:**

My SpringBoot application uses Spring Security.

In its Security context it defines:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()                
            .antMatchers("/api/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/api/login")
            .antMatchers(POST, "/api/**")
            .hasAuthority(ADMIN)
    }
}
```

My test code is initialized as a SpringBoot Test:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MySpringBootApplication.class)
public class ContractVerifierBase {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(context);
    }
}
```

My test sends s POST request to /api/login and although I expect a `401` to be rturned, a `404` is returned.

```java
ResponseOptions response = given().spec(request.post("/api/login");
```

Why is it not finding the `/api/login`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass to rest assured in the base class basic authentication data. E.g.

```
@Before
    public void setup() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.authentication =
                RestAssuredMockMvc.basic("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2", "");
    }
```